# Shell Integration

Tags: integration

Define y=$e^x cos(x)$ over the interval [0, π]. Consider the area of the region R bounded by the curve y=$e^x cos(x)$, the lines $x=π/2$, $x=π$ and the x-axis. I want to find the volume generated when R is rotated 2$π$ radians about the x-axis. Now, obviously, this can be done by the disc method, specifically, Volume=π∫e^(2x)cos^2(x) dx, over the interval [π/2, π].  However, I am interested in finding out whether the volume can be evaluated using shell method. The trouble lies in trying to find the inverse of y=$e^x cos (x)$, which in my opinion, is impossible. So, I tried to avoid this issue by defining a parametrisation for the curve instead: $x=t$, $y=e^t cos(t)$. Thus the volume is then: π^2e^(2π)- |2π ∫ t*e^t*cos(t)*e^t*(cos t - sin t) dt|, over the interval [π,π/2]. But in my opinion, this seems a little convenient as the parametrization seems a little trivial. So, I was wondering how to rigorously explain the validity of the parametrisation, such as a physical interpretation of the internal, or if there is some logical gap somewhere?[image: Evaluation by Shell Method]